# Replace parts in a string using REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

Hi I have a string in oracle like this:

```
 temp_a, temp_b, temp_c
```

What I want to get is :

```
 e.temp_a, e.temp_b, e.temp_c
```

So I want to put an "e." before every part in this string
I searched in internet and I found examples to split the string or to replace simpler strings but nothing to guide me through my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select regexp_replace('temp_a, temp_b, temp_c',
              '([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(,?)', 
               'e.\1\2') from dual;
```

This should work.

Comment: Upvoted because it works and it's what was asked for. I agree with Patrick that there's no need for regex here, and I would tend to avoid them (in Oracle) whenever there's a reasonably readable alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed you're specifically asking for regex, but for what it's worth I would probably do it like this:

```
rtrim( replace( 'e.'||your_string, ', ', ', e.'), 'e.')
```

Comment: No I want it generic. This is just an example

Comment: Thought it was too easy. :) Generic in what ways though? What would be constant and what not? Always comma separated values, always the "e." prefix?

Comment: always comma separated and always the e. prefix. The words will be changing

Comment: While regular expressions are fun and enjoyable, I think there is no need for them here.  It is all about the right tool/function for the right circumstance.  Maheswaran does provide a good regular expression alternative.